# Update nested field if a path to it isn't constant

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I'm working on Django which uses MongoDB.
One of collections has the following structure:

```
{
    "inspectionType" : {
        "id" : "59a79e44d12b52042104c1e8",
        "name" : "Example Name",
        "inspMngrsRole" : [
            {
                "id" : "55937af6f3de6c004bc42862",
                "type" : "inspectorManager",
                "is_secret_shoper" : false
            }
        ],
        "scopes" : {
            "56fcf6736389b9007a114b10" : {
                "_cls" : "SomeClass",
                "id" : "56fcf6736389b9007a114b10",
                "name" : "Example Name",
                "category" : "Example Category"
            },
        }
    }
}
```

I need to update field "_cls" ("inspectionType.scopes.._cls") for all documents in the collection.
The problem is the scope_id is dynamic and unique for each scope.
Is it possible to use db.collection.update for that?
And how should the path to the field look like?

**Update:**
MongoDB version: 3.6.7

Comment: If you are using MongoDB 4.2, this might be possible by giving update a pipeline that uses $objectToArray to normalize the fields so you can update the embedded document, then $arrayToObject to reconsitute it with the new value.

Comment: Thank you Joe. Unfortunately, the version is 3.6.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update using an aggregation (if you are using MongoDB version lesser than 4.2) plus an update operation ***or*** the `updateMany` method (if using version 4.2 or later) as follows:

```
# 1

var NEW_VALUE = "some new value"    // the value to be updated

db.collection.aggregate( [
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          "inspectionType.scopes": { $objectToArray: "$inspectionType.scopes" } 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          "inspectionType.scopes.v._cls": NEW_VALUE 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $addFields: { 
           "inspectionType.scopes": { $arrayToObject: "$inspectionType.scopes" } 
      } 
  }
] ).forEach( doc => db.scopes.updateOne( { _id: doc._id }, { $set: { "inspectionType.scopes": doc.inspectionType.scopes } } ) )
```

Starting MongoDB version 4.2 the `updateMany` can use an aggregation pipeline for the update operation; see [Update with Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html#update-with-aggregation-pipeline).

```
# 2

db.collection.updateMany(
  { },
  [
      { 
          $set: { 
              "inspectionType.scopes": { $objectToArray: "$inspectionType.scopes" } 
          } 
      },
      { 
          $set: { 
              "inspectionType.scopes.v._cls": NEW_VALUE 
          } 
      },
      { 
          $set: { 
               "inspectionType.scopes": { $arrayToObject: "$inspectionType.scopes" } 
          } 
      }
  ]
)
```

Comment: prasad_, thank you for the answer. I've just checked. The version - 3.6.7.

Comment: Anything above _version 3.4.4_ can use the _first_ (**# 1**) update method (of the two I had posted): `db.collection.aggregate( [ ...] ).forEach(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer!
Will try.